# Excel VBA - copying and pasting visible table rows only

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy only the visible rows in a table into a seperate worksheet in the same workbook. I'm a little new to using the 'ListObject' approach to dealing with tables (for a few reasons, referencing the table directly is a better approach here in terms of the rest of my module)

Below is my best attempt, when I run it I get 'run-time error '438'' on the `'Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A1").Paste'` line, I've been scouring the internet for an hour now trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, how do I need to re-phrase it so that it pastes the copied data into another sheet/table? Any assistance would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Adam

```
Private Sub CopyVisibleAreaOfTable(ByVal TableName As String)

Const FN_NAME As String = "CopyVisibleAreaOfTable"
On Error GoTo catch

    Dim TargetTable As ListObject
    Dim NumberOfAreas As Long

    Set TargetTable = Sheets("Adj1").ListObjects(TableName)

    ' Check that there are fewer than 8192 seperate areas
    With TargetTable.ListColumns(1).Range
        NumberOfAreas = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells.Count
        Debug.Print NumberOfAreas
    End With

    If NumberOfAreas = 0 Then
        'Do something to trigger an error message
    Else

        TargetTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A1").Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If

finally:
    Exit Sub

catch:
    Call ErrorReport(FN_NAME, True, Err.Number, Err.Description, "Table Name: " & TableName)
    Resume finally

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` instead of `.Paste`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specify the destination as part of the `.Copy` method:

```
TargetTable.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Sheet8").Range("A1")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, many thanks! As a side note, is there an easy way so that it pastes only the data in the source table, excluding the headers?

Comment: Ignore that, the solution is to change the code to use 'DataBodyRange' rather than just 'Range' in the line that copies the data. Thanks again for your help! Adam

Comment: @AnonymousType well I don't know if it's "legendary" but you're very wecome! :)