# Copy data with specified date from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to the VBA and would like some help.

My goal is to copy data during a specific period from a workbook that collects data every minute and used by many people.

Steps highlighted below:

1-open source
2- use specified start and end date
3- remove any existing filters on the table >>> this is important because many people use it and I want it with no filters
4- Filter for start/end date
5- Filter in ascending order
6- Copy all data including headers
7-Paste all data into destination
8-remove all filters from source and close wo saving

Here is my code below: Thanks

```
Sub Copydated()

'Disabling screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declaring two variables of Date data type
Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date
Dim wbd, wbs As Workbook
Dim shd, shs, shi As Worksheet

Set wbd = ThisWorkbook
Set shd = wbd.Sheets("Data Dump")
Set shi = wbd.Sheets("Instruction")
Set wbs = Workbooks.Open("path")

'Initializing the Date variables with start/end date
StartDate = shi.Range("B3").Value
EndDate = shi.Range("D3").Value


'Activating the worksheet object and filter
'Filter the data based on date range between starting date and end date

wbs.Activate
    Rows("1:1").Select
    wbs.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table_lebsqlprodmo.advics.local_CaliperData_PerformTestData") _
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wbs.Sheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
    wbs.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table_lebsqlprodmo.advics.local_CaliperData_PerformTestData") _
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate
    wbs.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects( _
        "Table_lebsqlprodmo.advics.local_CaliperData_PerformTestData").Sort.SortFields. _
        Add Key:=Range("Table_lebsqlprodmo.advics.local_CaliperData_PerformTestData[[#All],[DataTime]]") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects( _
        "Table_lebsqlprodmo.advics.local_CaliperData_PerformTestData").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

'Select all data and copy
        Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy

'Paste data into desti
shd.Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Remove filter from source and close
wbs.Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
wbs.Close savechanges:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/issue then? Not sure there is one yet.

Comment: Forgot to mention the problem LOL. It only copies the header

Comment: I would [copy visible cells from the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039774/excel-vba-copying-and-pasting-visible-table-rows-only)